# Force date time to time zone when setting variable using Mule expression language

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio, mel

I am using Anypoint Studio 6.1 and Mule 3.8.1 and I want to set a variable with todays date and time e.g. Thu, 2 Mar 2017 22:00:28 GMT but the variable is set it is being set as Thu, 2 Mar 2017 22:00:28 UTC.  How can I force it to show in GMT in the application as I cannot change server settings for this?

My MEL expression that does this is:

```
#[server.dateTime.format("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z")]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here's the MEL you need on that scenario:

## [server.dateTime.withTimeZone('GMT').format('EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z')]

Comment: best answer, helps me a lot today

Answer (score 1):

This can be helpful just a forum blog post.If you are looking for MEL the above answer would be enough

https://support.mulesoft.com/s/article/ka434000000TOwlAAG/How-to-properly-set-the-TimeZone-in-Mule-Mule-Runtime-and-CloudHub